# How to call functions and variables from a dictionary or a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to print a string, call functions and variables in a line.
such as [Hello! %(job), %(name)s, (function_name)]->[`Hello! student, John, This is the function.`]

**json01.json**

```
{
    "test" : "Hello! %(job), %(name)s, (function_name)"
}
```

**test01.py**

```
import json

a = 'test'
name = 'John'
job = 'student'

def function_name(message):
    print(message)

with open('json01.json') as json_file:
    json_dict = json.load(json_file)

if a in json_dict:
    print(json_dict[a] %locals())
#This works if there's only variables in the value
#but I don't know how to call functions when the value is not only function's name but also variables..
```

Is there any simple way to print whatever they are in the value?
or is there another way to do this work?

Sorry for the poor explanation and Thank you!

Comment: Try use `eval()`

Comment: Oh, yes I have used eval() and it works but I want to do this without using eval().. any idea?

Comment: Hmm for calling variable from a string, I can only come up `eval()` function.

Comment: hmm.. maybe it's impossible to call variables and functions together from a string without `eval()`..?

Comment: Do you want to pass an argument to the function?

Comment: @Erich Yes if possible! if not, at least I want to call functions

Comment: Do you want to replace the function's name with the return value of the function?

Comment: umm... if I do, is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: In my answer I replaced the function's name's with the return values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own function replacer using regular expressions. I defined an example syntax here as: `Hello, !(function_name)` where `function_name` is the name of the function that is called.

Using regular expressions we find all occurences of a function call and try to
evaluate them one by one. If successfull, we replace the function's name with the return value.

```
import re

def runfunctions(string):
    # find all functions defined with our syntax
    funcs = re.findall(r'!\((.*?)\)', string)
    result = string
    # iterate through found functions
    for func in funcs:
        try:
            # try to evaluate with globals()[func]() and replace function call
            # with return value
            result = re.sub(r'!\(' + func + r'\)', globals()[func](), result)
        except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
            # if func is not callable or does not exist catch error
            print("Error while evaluating functions in string:", e)
    # return final result
    return result
```

Note: I used `globals` instead of `locals` as otherwise the function is not found.

You can use it like this:

```
if a in json_dict:
    replaced_vars = json_dict[a] % locals()
    replaced_funcs = runfunctions(replaced_vars)
    print(replaced_funcs)
```

Comment: If you want to pass arguments to the functions, you would have to clarify, which arguments you want to pass. This would probably need additional syntax